# Generators of a direct product of $\Bbb Z_2$ with $\Bbb Z_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, direct-product

> Given two groups :
>
> $$\mathbb{Z} _{2} \;( =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$$
>
> $$\mathbb{Z}_{4} \;( =\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) $$
>
> We define the direct product :
>
> $$G =\mathbb{Z} _{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}  $$

I know $G$ is not cyclic as there is no element of order eight.

> But can we find two elements that generate $G$?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Yes, of course. The element that generates $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the element that generates $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two generators that go together are $([1]_2, [0]_4)$ and $([0]_2, [1]_4)$, where $[a]_n:=\{a+bn\mid b\in\Bbb Z\}.$

Comment: Does (1,1) work ?

Comment: No, @SkyLand77, since then the group would be cyclic.

Comment: Alright thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_4=\langle (1,0),(0,1)\rangle $.